# Import CSV of users by samAccountName - check if enabled/disabled - also check for membership of certain group

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to automate and need some help with a Powershell script.

I'd like to import a CSV with a list of users with a header of samAccountName, then export a CSV with additional columns.

1. Account is enabled/disabled.
2. A third column to show if they are members of a specific security group.

I was able to find this script below from another user, but I need assistance with the security group piece. Thank you in advance...

```
    $UserCSV   = "PATH"
$OutputCSV = "PATH"

$Users = Import-Csv -Path $UserCSV |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$Results =foreach( $User in $Users ){
    $Account = Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $User }

    if( $Account ){
        $Account | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Enabled
        }
    else{
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $User
            Enabled        = 'Account Not Found'
            }
        }
    }

$Results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputCSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What is the error you encountered when you tried to modify the script to fit your needs? For example, what specific assistance do you need with the "security group piece"?

Comment: Could you please explain your approach at solving the problem and what have you tried?